# Can one force multipath?

Tags: block-device, multipath-storage

Imagine I have a number of block devices, that I know are the same device but who have different identificators (it may be a device cut and clued with `dmsetup`, exported multiple times through iSCSI, etc.). I can guarantee the same volume of them, yet they may have different types (physical device and FC target, for instance). I want to multipath them via `multipath` util.

`man` reads, that I can force different *policies*, but can I force multipath *maps* themselves? Whatever is the method for detecting path failure, whatever is the path priority policy, it does not depend on device type or their serial/IQN, so I see no conceptual problem in here. However, I do not find anything like that in documentation.

Any ideas?

Comment: Take a look at http://www.sourceware.org/lvm2/wiki/MultipathUsageGuide; there are also further links at the end.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it was possible to create iSCSI target from SAS-connected device and export it to self to make it part of multipath, but it's more like a hack than *force*.

Steps are as follows:

1) `dmsetup create disk_full --table '0 781422768 linear /dev/sdb 0'` - we create `dmsetup`-ed disk from physical disk with full size

2) `echo "50011731011379ec" > /sys/kernel/config/target/core/iblock_0/disk_full/wwn/vpd_unit_serial` - we set the serial the same as the physical disk we want to multipath

3) `targetcli /iscsi/iqn.2017-12.com.aa.iscsi:srv/tpg1/luns create /backstores/iblock/disk_full` - we add our disk to the portal (it was created earlier)

4) `iscsiadm -m node -l` - we login to both remote machine with iSCSI target and *our own*

5) `service multipathd start` - we start multipath daemon if have not already

6) `multipath -ll` - voilà, here we have out multipathed disks

Note: without `dmsetup` trick I could never get the same serials: physical disk serial looks like `50011731011379ec` even after export to LIO, while `dmsetup`-ed disk after LIO export gets `600140550011731011379ec000000000` serial, the same as the remote iSCSI target's serial.